# Swap two symlinks

Tags: linux, unix

I have two symlinks:

```
folderA -> /home/www1
folderB -> /home/www2
```

How to swap them (atomically) and get:

```
folderA -> /home/www2
folderB -> /home/www1
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean by "atomically"?

Answer (score 2):

You can swap them via a temporary:

```
mv folderA folderTmp
mv folderB folderA
mv folderTmp folderB
```

or by rewriting their contents.

I'm afraid the Unix filesystem won't allow you to write to two files in one atomic step, though.

Comment: Although, a single `mv` is atomic.